# Uniform covers and partitions of unity

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

A cover $\mathcal C$ of a uniform space $(X,\mathcal U)$ is called a *uniform cover* if there is $U\in \mathcal U$ such that the cover $\{U(x):x\in X\}$ refines $\mathcal C$.

Is it true that to every uniform cover of a uniform space one can subordinate an equiuniformly continuous partition of unity? Is this true for any uniform space or some condition has to be taken like that of paracompactness?